# bokeh command in conda virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, bokeh

I want to run the bokeh command (e.g. to run a bokeh server) within a virtual environment created with the conda command.  It seems that bokeh as called by the bokeh command is always the bokeh installed in my base conda environment.

For example, I have bokeh v0.12.13 installed in my base conda environment.  Then I create a new conda environment where bokeh v0.10.0 is installed.  When running the bokeh command within this new conda environment, it is bokeh v0.12.13 that is recognized.

The image below demonstrates this in action on my Windows laptop.  How should something like this be done properly...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bokeh` command was introduced in version `0.11`, it did not exist in version `0.10`. The reason running `bokeh` works at all in the situation you describe is because you have *both* the old and new environments in your execution `PATH`, and it is being picked up from the new one (the only one it exists in).

Prior to version `0.11` there was a `bokeh-server` command. However I must state unequivocally that that this old, first generation version of the Bokeh server (which was never truly functional) is now ***100% deprecated and completely unsupported***. It should not be used by anyone for any reason in new code. I would likewise say that use of Bokeh version `0.10` at all is also to be highly discouraged, as it is ancient at this point.